# Transfer messages between devices on same network in Sencha Touch

Tags: android, ios, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am looking at designing a app where all the devices in the same network should be able to communicate with each other. The dicovery would be taken care because all the devices will have a static IP. Is there a way that use in sencha touch to communicate between the devices?

I am completely new to sencha touch and exploring if we can use this for our requirements.

Any help or directions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can implement this in sencha touch,but for this you will also have to use other plugin also You can  refer to below link for more information.

1. cordova or phonegap plugin, There are couple of plugin available in cordova and plugin Ex: 
   https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial
2. Using socket.io
   http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?118453-Mobile-Chat-with-Sencha-Touch-node.js-socket.io